# What's the difference between oriention 0 and 360 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In experimenting with JavaScript window.orientation, I have found a few references to window.orientation == 360 and was wondering what exactly is the difference between window.orientation == 0 and window.orientation == 360 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference at all.

Once you go round a circle and reach 360, you are back to the start, so the angle becomes 0, and you can go again, and 720 becomes 0 again...

It is same as `window.orientation == 2160`.

Comment: Also, it's the same as 720. And 1080.

Comment: It's also the same as `3599999640`